# Javascript array changed to object act weird

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```js
let test = [];
test.someProp = "haha";
console.log(test); // result:  [ someProp: 'haha' ]
console.log(JSON.stringify(test)); // result: []
console.log(test.someProp); // result: haha
console.log(JSON.stringify(test)); // result: []
```

How `console.log(test)` returns an object and the line after it `console.log(JSON.stringify(test))` returns an empty array ?

Comment: You can't represent arrays-with-extra-props in JSON.

Comment: Specifically, https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-json.stringify point 5 tells us what happens when you stringify an array, which tells us that it doesn't even look at the array as an "object", it already knows what arrays look like and serializes accordingly. Which is one of the reasons why you shouldn't add custom properties to built-ins: "polluting" any built-in is just going to lead to confusion, bugs, or more likely, both =)

Comment: JSON is, at the end of the day, a text format with a [*reasonably* well-defined specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). Imagine you are the person writing the definition of JSON.stringify. How would you represent your example as JSON according to the rules of that format? You can't. Remember too that _lots_ of things speak JSON, not just Javascript (see the list at the bottom of the link), can what you're attempting be represented in all those other languages once deserialized?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not sure where exactly you mean by point 5 there..? The 5th item in the numbered list is referring specifically to the 'replacer' parameter, and the 5th note below the list only references arrays to say that unrepresentable types will be replaced by nulls when inside arrays.

Comment: Good point, that's entirely the wrong point-and-link. the part about it knowing what an array looks like and serializing accordingly is still correct, but it's covered by https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-serializejsonarray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out, JSON can't represent an array with extra properties.

However, if you need to translate such an array into JSON and back, you can do it like this:

```js
let test = [4,5,6]

test.someProp = 'haha'

let json = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, test))

console.log(json)

let test2 = Object.assign([], JSON.parse(json))

console.log(test2)

console.log(test2.someProp)

console.log(Array.isArray(test2))

console.log(test2.length)
```

Comment: Clever trick. Probably *too* clever, but clever nevertheless.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let test = [];
test.someProp = "haha";
console.log(test); // result: []
console.log(JSON.stringify(test)); // result: []
console.log(test.someProp); // result: haha
console.log(JSON.stringify(test)); // result: []
```

The reason you can see someProp: 'haha' is because the console interprets the object differently on different dev tools. On the SO snippet tool, as you can see, the result is []. Here is why:

Arrays in JS are objects with numeric keys. Because they are objects, they can have properties like your someProp. This doesn't add an element to the array (which would require a numeric index). That is why you might see [someProp: 'haha']. Some consoles use the names of the props and values to print the object to help devs with debugging. When you log test.someProp, it accesses only the property you asked for as a value.

When you JSON.stringify, it converts only the array elements into the JSON string because you called it on the array. That is why you once more see [].

Comment: Please edit this to add some full stops and correct all those typos.

Comment: Sorry English is not my first language @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score -2):

In brief, this quote [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) should shed some light on this:

> In JavaScript, arrays aren't primitives but are instead Array objects

The `Array` is still an `Array`. It is *also*, and always was, an `Object` too. How a given type of `Object` is converted to JSON will usually depend on the `toJSON()` method of its prototype, though in the case of `Array` (being a built in type) it is treated as a special case and has a default implementation which doesn't, for example, output the `length` property of `Array` in the stringified output but rather the `[...]` format you see.

Comment: It's not clear how any of this is relevant to the OP's question: 1. `toString` is not called during serialization 2. Arrays are objects, but why aren't their properties serialized the way every other object's are (because arrays are *[exotic objects](https://blog.bitsrc.io/exotic-objects-understanding-why-javascript-behaves-so-moody-5f55e867354f)* and treated differently by the JSON serializer, which your answer doesn't mention) 3. This has nothing to do with prototypes, functional programming, or curly-brace syntax so why mention any of that? How does this actually answer the question asked?

Comment: Your edit is still wrong: arrays do not have a `toJSON` method. I kinda wish you *could* overload JSON serialization behavior for user-defined types, but you can't.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't process the specific aspect of `JSON.stringify()` in the question originally so the original second half of my answer wasn't relevant.
As for how prototypes and such is relevant, the point I was trying to convey is that a given type of object can control how it is converted to a JSON string, that Array objects have a built-in default representation, and that if one where to add a `toJSON()` method to `test`you could make it output anything you wanted as the JSON representation, just like you can arbitrarily add `someProp`, this being broadly how prototype based systems work.

Comment: `Array.prototype.toJSON = function(){return "banana")`, for example, makes `Array` objects output as the string `banana` when passed into `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Yup. I've removed my DV